# comparar registros y saber si existen duplicados

Tags: mysql

tengo varios registros asociados a un numero de documento para este caso es 300104151, requiero leer el primer registro y compararlo con los demás, saber si ese registro esta duplicado cuando cumpla las condiciones de valor y shortname. que cuando haga esto pase al segundo registro y haga lo mismo y en secuencia hasta terminar las comparaciones

la tabla se ve así

```
ShortName   Account Debit   Credit  Proyect LineMemo
 26200501   26200501    0   44000   03  ASISTENCIA 174658
 24959502   24959502    0   110000  03  FONDO 174658
 31050501   31050501    0   30000   03  CAPITALIZACION174658
 16250501   16250501    0   100000  03  CAPITALIZACION174658
 24452503   24452503    0   23000   03  RETENCION  174658
 24480503   24480503    0   8510    03  ICA  174658
 P4598921   16250501    0   1540000 03  ANTICIPO MC174658
 P4598921   27959501    0   437490  03  PAGAR 174658
 27400501   27400501    2200000 0   03  LIQUIDACION
 27400501   27400501    100000  0   03  SOBRECOSTO 
 26200501   26200501    0   2000    03  ASISTENCIA 174658 SOBRECOSTO
 24959502   24959502    0   5000    03  FONDO 174658 SOBRECOSTO
 26200501   26200501    0   44000   03  ASISTENCIA 174658 SOBRECOSTO
```

estoy ejecutando la consulta

```
SELECT
ShortName,
COUNT(ShortName),
Credit
FROM
zliquidasap
WHERE
ShortName = '26200501'
AND SecManifiesto = '300104151'
GROUP BY
ShortName, Credit
HAVING
ShortName > 1
```

lo que me retorna
shortname cuenta valor
26200501    1   2000
26200501    2   44000
en el segundo registro  de la columna cuenta me regresa un 2, indicador que esta duplicado con las condiciones de la consulta.

pero no se como almacenar ese resultado por ejemplo en comparar1, pasar al siguiente registro e iniciar la comparación y dejarla en comparar2, hasta que termine de leer todos los registros.

gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Faltan detalles en tu pregunta, pero a lo que se entiende debes hacer un join y agrupar por los campos que deciden si es unico el registro o tiene duplicados. es decir:

```sql
SELECT
  ShortName,
  COUNT(ShortName) as duplicados,
  Credit
FROM
  zliquidasap as tablaA
LEFT JOIN otraTabla as tablaB on tablaA.ShortName = tablaB.ShortName
GROUP BY
  tablaA.ShortName, Credit --campos que deciden si es duplicado
HAVING --tal vez sea WHERE en lugar de HAVING
  duplicados > 1
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero no puede ser con join, puesto que la tabla que deseo comparar registros es unica. solo es como la coloca en la pregunta inicial.

Comment: 1. el campo SecManifiesto de donde proviene?
2. en ese caso solo quita el join y estara lista tu consulta